# Raspbian sftp error. Can't log in

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ssh

I have the following issue. When I try to login as the pi user with the local IP adders I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.101 port 22: Connection refused
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I am not listening on port 22 at all, as I have changed the ssh port to something else.

And if I try using the external IP, I get this error:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I can ssh into it just fine with both internal and external IPs. I have bound the internal IP and setup port forwarding.

Any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/264046/how-to-ssh-on-a-port-other-than-22

Comment: 'When I try to login as the pi user with the local IP adders[sic] I get this error:'   and then 'I can ssh into it just fine with both the internal and external IPs'  .  This is confusing.  It would be better to state the IP addresses in use and which ones have a problem.  If you are trying to ssh to the unit and have moved sshd to a port other than 22 then you'll have to specify the port in your ssh connection/command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just had to provide the server with my public key and use the IdentityFile option for sftp.

Thus, the command is :

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/file -oPort=port user@address
```